# Apple LLVM 6.0 error when XCode 5.0 project run on XCode 6.0

Tags: xcode6

I have a created a project in XCode 5.0, it's working fine. But when tried to run the same project with XCode 6.0 it gives Apple LLVM 6.0 error!

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/...../Duro-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Comment: Could you share more information on what kind of error?

Comment: Its gives error with .pch file

Comment: Apparently it cannot find the file. Check your paths and build settings if they are correct.

Comment: Ok. But the same project when i tried to run with XCode 5.0 it works fine. Is there is changes to be done when we run XCode 5.0 project on XCode 6.0?

Comment: You shouldn't have to. But just recheck if your prefix path is correct.